# website.com/index.php/page works but website.com/page doesn't

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, laravel-5, hosting

Here is the website I'm specifically talking about: http://anomet.com.
The home page loads fine, but navigating to another page doesn't, unless it's prefixed with index.php. For example: http://anomet.com/index.php/lighting works, but http://anomet.com/lighting doesn't. The website was created using Laravel 5.4.15. The website is hosted on Bell's server, and when I called them, they said mod_rewrites should be enabled. I have proper permissions set on my storage folder as well (755), since I've read that not having proper permissions on the Laravel folder can cause this problem. Here is my .htaccess file below:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>
    RewriteEngine On
    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>


AddHandler phpCGI .xml .php
Action phpCGI /cgi-bin/php5.6fcgi
# for php5 and securewebexchange
<IfDefine SSL>
    AddHandler phpCGI .xml .php
    Action phpCGI https://secure9.securewebexchange.com/anomet.com/cgi-bin/php5.6fcgi
</IfDefine>
```

Is Bell wrong in saying that mod_rewrites is enabled? The tech support person didn't sound confident on the phone, and they didn't actually check the configuration files (i.e. httpd.conf or apache.conf) to see if it had anything like `AllowOverride All` or `Require all granted` inside of it.

Lastly, I have the exact same files uploaded to a Namecheap server (https://kdev.solutions/) and everything works on there, which further leads me to believe that the problem is with Bell's server configuration.